# Will Samsung's auto-restarts feature disable your alarm?

Tags: samsung, reboot, alarm

I'm using the Samsung Galaxy A32 5G on Android 13. It has a feature to auto-restart the device.

I noticed auto-restarts close all background apps on the restart and was wondering if this affects your basic clock alarm app wake-up sound. Will it disable it?

Comment: Wouldn't this just be worthy of a self-conducted experiment? You can self-reply to your post, for the benefit of all.

Comment: @wbogacz That's a good point, I'll see if an alarm goes off after a restart.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, when my phone restarts in the night, the "Sleep as Android" app doesn't restore properly, but I am woken at the correct time by a default alarm app that I believe comes from the Android OS. YMMV though, so I recommend enabling auto-restart on a rest day first.

Comment: Thank you! I'll check if the alarm still works after a manual restart.